# How to concat multiple df side by side with common column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have `N` number of DataFrames. Every DataFrame has two columns, the first column is always constant with a `date` and another column name is dynamic. So for example

`df1`

```
date            A
2017-12-31      5
2020-12-31      7
2021-12-31      8
```

`df2`

```
date            B
2012-12-31      9
2020-12-31      6
```

and so on. So I want to have a resultant `result_df` which will have all the `date` along with the columns side-by-side like this

`result_df`

```
date            A     B    ...
2012-12-31      -     9    ...
2017-12-31      5     -    ...
2020-12-31      7     6    ...
2021-12-31      8     -    ...
```

*Special case* - I have few empty DataFrames too. I would like that to merge into `result_df`, for example an empty DataFrame with columns `['date', 'C']` will be added like this

`result_df`

```
date            A     B     C    ...
2012-12-31      -     9     -    ...
2017-12-31      5     -     -    ...
2020-12-31      7     6     -    ...
2021-12-31      8     -     -    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `concat` + `groupby` + `first`:

```
dfX = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date','C'])
dfs = [df1, df2, dfX]
out = pd.concat(dfs).groupby('date', as_index=False).first().fillna('-')
```

Output:

```
         date    A    B  C
0  2012-12-31    -  9.0  -
1  2017-12-31  5.0    -  -
2  2020-12-31  7.0  6.0  -
3  2021-12-31  8.0    -  -
```

Comment: 1. I have multiple dfs. So `df1` and `df2` will not work. 2. Column `C` is not a customised column, its coming from an emplty `dfX`.

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' updated the answer; is it something you have in mind?

Comment: Yes. Why we are using `first()` though?

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' because `concat` creates duplicate dates, one for each DataFrame (with corresponding NaNs). We "squeeze" the data back up to remove NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at pd.merge: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html
in your case the following code should work

```
df1.merge(df2, on='date', how='outer')
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can do this. But wanted to know if there is an easy way for **multiple** dfs.

Comment: Based on above answer pd.merge([df1, df2, df3]) 
and so on should work as suggested by @enke above